# Cannot add inline attachment with actionmailer in rails 3

Tags: mime-types, actionmailer, inline-attachments

After a bundle install I am no longer able to add inline images to attachments. This is the error I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `type_for' for MIME::Types:Class):
  app/mailers/welcome_mailer.rb:14:in `add_inline_attachment!'
```

So clearly the `type_for` method is being called on a class instead of an object.

Here is how I add the inline attachment, it follows the [guidelines from ActionMailer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L210):

```ruby
attachments.inline['photo.png'] = File.read('path/to/photo.png')
```

I have tested that the file indeed exists and that it gets read. The issue appears to be gem-related.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to mime-types 3.1, released on 22 May 2016. mime-types 2.x only has six more planned updates and reaches end of life in November 2017, after which point no more support will be provided at all.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the update `mime-types` gem, which is a dependency from `ActionMailer` was updated from version `2.99.1` to version `3.0`, since this gem was not locked. It was pulled in as a dependency only.

From `Gemfile.lock`:

```
mime-types (3.0)
  mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
```

Explicitly adding `gem mime-types, (< 3)` to the `Gemfile` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I’m not sure what the error is, but I’m 99% sure that it isn’t the correct fix because that part of the mime-types code did *not* change. Someone has reported the issue to mime-types, but any details you can add to this issue will help me either fix the issue on mime-types (unlikely) or get the correct fix upstream (more likely). https://github.com/mime-types/ruby-mime-types/issues/117