# Error when uploading from local file: undefined method `type_for' for MIME::Types:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am creating a Rails 4 application, which uses Carrierwave 1.2.1. The problem I am having is when I run `rake db:reset`. Everything goes fine, until seeding the database. The error is:

```html
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `type_for' for MIME::Types:Class
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:271:in `content_type'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:226:in `copy_to'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:134:in `cache!'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:43:in `block in cache'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:41:in `map'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:41:in `cache'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:146:in `lender_document_file='
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-b31f7ce006ba/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:70:in `lender_document_file='
(APP_PATH)/db/seeds.rb:92:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:198:in `load_seed'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:174:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/MASTER/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:133:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/MASTER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/MASTER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The seed file has this, on the indicated line (92):

```
@lender.lender_document_file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/afra.png")
```

The `Lender` model has: `mount_uploader :lender_document_file, ReceiptUploader`

And this is the `ReceiptUploader`:

```html
# encoding: utf-8

class ReceiptUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  if Rails.env.test? or Rails.env.cucumber? or Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.demo?
    storage :file

    def store_dir
      "uploads_marketplace/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
  else

    storage :fog

    def store_dir
      "uploads_marketplace/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
  end

  def default_url
    #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
    #
    #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

end
```

I am using Carrierwave version 1.2.1, mime-types (3.0, 2.99.1, 2.99, 2.6.2) and mime-types-data (3.2016.0221).

Comment: try `rake db:migrate:reset` or `rake db:drop` then `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: what do u have in seed file `db/seeds.rb:92` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly adding `gem 'mime-types'` to my `Gemfile` fixed the issue.
I based myself on this question: [Cannot add inline attachment with actionmailer in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709845/cannot-add-inline-attachment-with-actionmailer-in-rails-3)